# How do I run Javascript tests in Windmill when using test_windmill for Django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, automated-tests, windmill

I'm using the Windmill test system and have it running using test_windmill for Django which works fine for the Python tests. I'd like this to run a suite of Javascript tests also whilst the Django test server is running. I've used the run_js_tests call from the Windmill shell which works fine but I can't find a way to have this run as part of the Python tests.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so couldn't find out how to do this so I'm running the website under Apache and using the windmill standard jstests parameter to run the Javascript tests against this.